# Discord.py Roles editing

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I got this role editing command to change colour and name

**My code:**

```py
@client.command()
async def editrole(ctx, role: discord.Role, colour: discord.Colour, name):
    await role.edit(colour = colour, name = name)
    embed = discord.Embed(
        description = (f'The changes for role {role} have been applied.'),
        colour = discord.Colour.orange()
    ) 
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

However I only want one of both to take effect, so for example if i say "editrole  <hexcode/colour>"
it will change the colour and keep the name.

And the other way around (only change name and keep the colour). Is that possible? I always have to enter both arguments to make things happen

I've heard typing.Optional[] but the defaults resets them for example name to "new role".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this to keep the `name` optional. But I don't think you can keep `colour` optional. If you want `colour` to be optional you can keep it as the last argument and default it to `None`, but then `name` won't be optional.

```py
@client.command()
async def editrole(ctx, role: discord.Role, colour: discord.Colour, *, name = None):
    await role.edit(colour = colour)
    if name != None:
        await role.edit(name = name)

    embed = discord.Embed(
        description = (f'The changes for role {role} have been applied.'),
        colour = colour
    ) 
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

So, you can either give only `colour` or both `colour` & `name`